# Facebook wall post using ajax post request inconsistent with Chrome and IE

Tags: debugging, facebook-graph-api, jquery, cross-browser

I am using the posted code for posting content to a Facebook wall.

```
FB.init({ appId: 'my app id', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true, oauth: true })
    $('#share_button').click(function (e) {
        if ($('#textfield').val() != 'Whats Happening' && $('#textfield').val() != '') {
            var lin = window.location.href;
            FB.login(function (response) {
                if (response.authResponse) {
                    console.log("User is connected to the application.");
                    var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                    var fbURL = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token=" + accessToken;
                    $.ajax({
                        url: fbURL,
                        data: "message=" + $('#textfield').val() + "&picture=MyUrl/images/logo.png&name=FutureZoom&link=MyUrl",
                        type: 'POST',
                        success: function (resp) {
                            $('#ValidationMessage').html(' Post has been shared on your wall!')
                                                   .css('color', 'green');
                            setTimeout(function () {
                                $('#ValidationMessage').html('');
                            }, 3000);
                        },
                        error: function (request, status, error) {
                            alert("Facebook Error :  \n" + request.responseText + '\n' + status + '\n' + error);                            
                        }
                    });
                }
            }, { scope: 'publish_stream' });
        }
        else {
            $('#ValidationMessage').html(' Please write something to share!')
                                   .addClass('red');
        }
    });
```

Above is working fine in Firefox browser but problem is with IE and Chrome.
In Chrome, above code posts the comment on wall but when returns, it goes into error block instead of success. Below is the error getting in chrome.

```
Facebook Error:
{
    "id": "100002506055900_30229318964214"
}
parseerror
SyntaxError: Unexpected token:
```

And in IE, nothing happens. Neither posts the comment nor returns in error/success block.

What could be reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing a AJAX call to post something to the user's timeline, you should use the `FB.api` function in the Facebook JavaScript SDK instead. It simplifies the process:

```
FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { message: body, picture: pic }, function(response) {
  if ( !response || response.error ) {
    alert('Error occured');
  } else {
    alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
  }
});
```

You can see the documentation for the JS call here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/

You will be able to reduce your code quite a bit by using this method.

Comment: Run your code through the JavaScript Linter and fix any errors. IE doesn't like it if there is a missing / extra comma or semicolon anywhere... It might fix the issue for you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
It worked for Firefox and chrome now. But nothing happens in IE.  
It asked for the permission to post on the wall first time but does not happen anything after that. Neither goes in If block nor in else block.